# Use Generic in JPA @OneToMany

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I have a class "Branch". Either classes "Dictionary" and "Link" which I want to use as < T> here.

```
@Entity
public class Branch<T> {
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<T> entities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

It throws a Runtime Exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property by.ipps.accounting.model.Branch.branches has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
```

If I use `targetEntity=SomeEntity.class` there is no benefits of generic.
How can I use generics here?

Comment: You could take a look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html) for entity inheritance and use the superclass for the mapping.

Comment: Thank you, I know that solution, but I'd want to avoid creating a parent class as superclass here because the subclasses are not so similar.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

The issue here is more in `Branch<T>` declaration than in `List<T> entities`. When JPA provider reads the record of Branch from database, how would it know what `T` is?

You would need to provide an interface/superclass instead of `T`, be it only an empty marker one if the differences between subclasses are large as in your case.

Comment: can you please provide an example regarding "need to provide an interface/superclass"?